# how do use `NeDB` in-browser for persistence between sessions?

Tags: nedb

The [documentation](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb/) says

> If you specify a filename, the database will be persistent, and automatically select the best storage method available (IndexedDB, WebSQL or localStorage) depending on the browser.

The very short example shows only in-memory usage. I am not sure what kind of a **filename** I can specify so that it makes sense to the client browser.

Suggestions?

**Update:** A little more context. I want to do offline storage in the client's browser and then sync to the server periodically (when connection is available). I am not sure if NeDB is the correct way to achieve this, so suggestion on this also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a filename and autoload... It works for me:

```
var db = new Nedb({
    filename: 'library.db',
    autoload: true
  });
```